# Cannot execute bash script in redhat linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I write a simple shell script to clean log files in redhat:

Filename: clean.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -f *.log core.*
```

But when I typed clean or clean.sh, it always prompt

```
-bash: clean: command not found
-bash: clean.sh: command not found
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problem 1: maybe the execute permission on clean.sh is not set. Do this:

```
chmod +x ./clean.sh
```

problem 2: RH Linux does not include CWD on the path by default. So, when you are in the same directory as clean.sh, type:

```
./clean.sh
```

That should execute it.

Comment: Just as you said, it doesn't has exe permission and need add ./

Answer (score 3):

You probably don't have `.` (the current directory) in your `$PATH` (and that's a good thing; having `.` in your `$PATH` can be dangerous.)

Try this:

```
./clean.sh
```

And if the script file's name is `clean.sh` you can't run it as just `clean`, with or without a directory.  The file name is `clean.sh`, and that's how you need to execute it.

Or you can change the name from `clean.sh` to just `clean`.  Unix-like systems (that includes Linux) don't depend on file extensions the way Windows does.